# ltrace : only show direct calls from a program to a library, and no inter-library call

Tags: linux, unix, trace, ltrace

When called with no argument other than the program to run, ltrace seems to display only the calls made by the program into shared libraries, and not the inter-library calls.

I'd like to filter down these results by selecting the library the calls are made into. The `-l` option filters the library, but the inter-library calls are shown also. Adding `-e '@my_program` does not do any difference.

`ltrace`'s [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) states that inter-library calls are removed by linking the program with `-Dsymbolic`.

Is there a way to get rid of the inter-library calls without recompiling the program?

Thanks